# Отправка запроса на сервер

Tags: javascript, jquery

На сервер отправляю запрос с JWT-ключем в  заголовке, в ответ сервер отправляет новую страницу. Вопрос, как изменить текущую страницу на новую (которую прислал сервер)?
пример Запроса:

```
function test() {
$.ajax
({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/restricted/hello",

    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + getSessionToken()
    },

    success: function (r) {
        console.log("log" + r) //r html-код страницы

    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Если я тебя правильно понял то так:

```
success: function(r){
   location.href="http://" + r;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю, ответ уже нашел)

Answer (score 0):

```
   success: function (r) {

        document.write(r)
    }
```